# Are there any utilities which support umount2(2)'s MNT_EXPIRE?

Tags: unmounting

[`man umount2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umount2.2.html)  says:

> ```
>    MNT_EXPIRE (since Linux 2.6.8)
>           Mark the mount point as expired.  If a mount point is not
>           currently in use, then an initial call to umount2() with this
>           flag fails with the error EAGAIN, but marks the mount point as
>           expired.  The mount point remains expired as long as it isn't
>           accessed by any process.  A second umount2() call specifying
>           MNT_EXPIRE unmounts an expired mount point.  This flag cannot
>           be specified with either MNT_FORCE or MNT_DETACH.
> ```

[`umount` doesn't seem to support it](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/issues/497).

Are there any utilities which allow one use this flag?

Comment: +1. I'm curious; what should this option do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily access C functions from Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys
from ctypes import *
libc = CDLL('libc.so.6', use_errno=True)
MNT_EXPIRE = 4
libc.umount2(c_char_p(sys.argv[1]), c_int(MNT_EXPIRE))
if get_errno() != 0:
    print os.strerror(get_errno())
    exit(1)
```